# Composite C1: how to make the page editor to display the source code by default

Tags: c1-cms

When you start editing a page, the editor is initially in the Visual mode, so every time you have to switch it to the Source mode if you prefer html-level editing as usually programmers do.
It is annoying when you have a lot of things to do during the day, especially when there is a bunch of languages every page is translated to.

I haven't found any option in the CMS and no solution in Google.
Actually I found myself the way to change this, so I post this question in order to instantly answer it. Maybe this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Edit file VisualEditorPageBinding.js, which is located in /Composite/content/misc/editors/visualeditor/bindings.

There is function VisualEditorPageBinding.prototype.initializeComponent.
Simply add this line at the very end of the function:

```
this.switchEditingMode();
```